# NSData* to std::vector<unsigned char> Without Copy

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, stdvector

If I have a NSData* from one API and need to turn that into an std::vector for another API, is there any way to do this safely without copying the bytes in the NSData (assume a very large NSData*)?

Comment: You might be able to create a custom allocator (the second template parameter of `std::vector`) that does this, but I don't think there's anything out-of-the-box that would do this for you.

Answer (score 5):

No quick solution that comes to mind, no.

If you create the NSData object (rather than it being returned by another API), you might consider subclassing `NSData` and/or `NSMutableData` when you really need to avoid the copy -- then you could access the storage (std::vector) directly.

You may also be able to sneak around it in some cases by creating the data with 'your' allocation:

```
NSData * data([[NSData alloc]
                 initWithBytesNoCopy:vector.data()
                              length:vector.size()
                        freeWhenDone:false]);
```

of course, you need to make sure the vector is not resized (or its backing store reallocated) before the `NSData` object is deallocated.

Sometimes you also need to consider changing the parameter type so that it is not a `std::vector`. A little container which has a `NSData` member and a vector-like interface, iterator, or begin+end may be adequate while accommodating other collections types.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough about stl or cpp, but if you can construct a vector from a void* buffer then you should be able to with:

```
void * buffer = [data bytes];
size_t len = [data length];
```

keep in mind that the data owns the buffer so you may not free it.